# ROS Answers SE migration: tf view_frames

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I was just wondering if anyone knows a way to generate a formated pdf from

rosrun tf view_frames

I want to include the frames.pdf that is generated in a report by it is very very wide.

Can I do something to get a more vertically oriented graph, that fits into an A4 or letter?

Thanks

Miguel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33513/tf-view_frames/) by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 254 on 2012-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

EDIT: If there are only a couple of figures, an easy solution is to modify the `frames.gv` file that gets generated when you run `rosrun tf view_frames`. You can modify this file to best represent the graph. The corresponding graph can then be generated using the `dot` command:

```
dot -Tpdf frames.gv -o frames.pdf
```

Other possible solutions:

1. If you want this to be done automatically, then it is a fairly difficult problem. It is easy to generate the dot file from the tf tree, but extra work needs to be done reason about the layout. You will have to figure out a way to get the tree from `TransformListener` and generate a `dot` file appropriately with some layout information. See how the current `dot` file is generated [here](http://www.ros.org/doc/diamondback/api/tf/html/c++/tf_8cpp_source.html#l00985).
2. Modify the graph in an SVG editor. I personally have never used one of these, so I cannot comment on it.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-12**:
Isn't the dot file already output (frames.gv)?

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-05-12**:
Excellent point. I have updated the answer based on this information. I think I have never bothered to open that file before.